# Updates Available not visible in EE CP

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, solspace-calendar

I have version 3.0.6 of the Calendar installed on my local EE and on our production environment. On my local EE CP, I see the 'updates available' at the bottom of the Calendar settings with a description of three updates but on our production CP, I do not see 'updates available' at all. Does anyone know why this could be?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your EE cache directory is not writeable, and Calendar isn't able to copy the changelog file over to it (necessary for Calendar Update service to display the contents in Calendar CP.

At any rate, as of writing this, Calendar 3.1.1 is available, and you can download the latest update from your account by [visiting your account](https://solspace.com/account/software).